# An if statement nested in a for loop : breaking from loop in the second iteration upon reaching condition check in if statement

Tags: c

```
declaration ( globale ) : 

    struct list
    {
        int v ;
        struct list *suivant ;
    };
    
    int i ;
    struct list *T_list = NULL, *courent = NULL ;
```

The following function test if a number is prime or not ; return 1 in case the number is prime and 0 if not :

```
int est_premier ( int x )
{
    for ( i = x/2 ; i > 1 ; i-- )
    {
        if ( x % i == 0 )
        {
            return 0 ;
        }
    }
    return 1 ;
}
```

I'm facing problem when calling "est_premier" function in the following code and testing it in the if statement ; the loop is supposed to create a linked list of prime numbers between 0 and x ( x included ), what happens is that the code is breaking from the loop as soon as it reaches the second iteration ignoring the if statement in the process.

The code with issues :

```
void Creer_L ( int x )
{
    for ( i = x ; i > 1 ; i-- )
    {
        if ( est_premier ( i ) == 1 )
        {
            courent = malloc ( sizeof ( struct list ) ) ;
            (*courent).v = i ;
            (*courent).suivant = T_list ;
            T_list = courent ;
        }
    }
}
```

calling the function in main :

```
int main()
{
    Creer_L ( 10 ) ;
    while ( T_list != NULL )
        {
            printf("%d ", (*T_list).v );
            T_list = (*T_list).suivant ;
        }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Input : 10

Expected output : 2 3 5 7 ( prime numbers between 0 and 10 )

The actual output : ( nothing)

but the program is terminated correctly.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Also give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Where is `i` declared?  I assume it's an `int`, but why would you use a global for an loop index?

Comment: `(*courent).v ` is more normally written `courent->v`.

Comment: @kaylum done, i hope that my latest edit satisfy the rules

Comment: "*so i don't need to redeclare it in each function*". That is a really really bad reason for using global variables. Don't do that - it is definetely wrong in your case as it is used in multiple functions and will cause endless problems with any serious code. Please update your code to show the local variable version as there is no point debugging code with that obvious error in  it (even if you claim fixing it does not solve all the problems it is still a major bug).

Comment: @kaylum thank you for the advice, indeed the declaration was the reason behind the problem, i shoul've declared it as locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your `i` that is declared as a global and used in both of your loops that creates this behaviour.

You probably want to declare it inside your loop

```
int est_premier ( int x )
{
    for (int i = x/2 ; i > 1 ; i-- )
    {
        if ( x % i == 0 )
        {
            return 0 ;
        }
    }
    return 1 ;
}
```

and

```
   for ( int i = x ; i > 1 ; i-- )
    {
        if ( est_premier ( i ) == 1 )
        {
            courent = malloc ( sizeof ( struct list ) ) ;
            (*courent).v = i ;
            (*courent).suivant = T_list ;
            T_list = courent ;
        }
    }
```

And you can remove it from you global declaration since you don't use it anywhere else.